# Inverse Function involving the natural exponential

Tags: functions

My question:

If $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$, show that $g^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(\ln{x})$.

It is also given that $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ have an inverse for $x>0$.

My efforts so far:

$y=e^{f(x)}$

$\ln{y}=f(x)$

$f^{-1}(\ln{y})=f^{-1}(f(x))$

$f^{-1}(\ln{y})=x$

I am not quite sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What characterizes invertible mappings?

Given some $f:X\to Y$ which is bijective, we say the $f^{-1}$ is its inverse iff
\begin{align*}
f(f^{-1}(y)) = y
\end{align*}

Since the function $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is bijective (over its range), the composition $\exp(f(x))$ is also bijective, provided that $f$ is bijective. Having said that, it results that
\begin{align*}
g(g^{-1}(y)) = \exp(f(g^{-1}(y))) = y & \Longleftrightarrow f(g^{-1}(y)) = \ln(y)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow g^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(\ln(y))
\end{align*}

just as desired.